# Где хранить настройки пользователя?

Tags: php, сервер

Задался вопросом где лучше хранить настройки пользователя?

1)в Сессиях - нет, ибо после выхода из аккаунта они уничтожаютсья. 
2)куки тоже нет. 
3)текстовый файл на сервере? врятли 
4)остается только одно, создать в таблице пользователя:

> а)один столбец, и дальше записать так:  
> ***param1=0;param2=0;param3=1.***
> А потом парсить и считывать конфигурацию.
>
> б)отдельний столбец для каждой настройки
> ***столбец_1 для param1  
>
>
>
> столбец_2 для param2***

Как по вашему мнению  удобней и эффективней хранить конфигурацию?

Comment: а чем куки не подходят?

Comment: @ivankaban, тем, что не обеспечивают постоянное хранение настроек пользователя.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в) создать отдельную таблицу `user_options`. Если есть таблица "пользователи", то это не значит, что в ней должно хранится вообще все.

UPD: Вместо названия option_name добавить ещё одну таблицу

```
optionID | optionName
   1     | last_login
```

Получим такую таблицу с настройками:

```
user | optionID | value
12   |     1    | 22-01-2014
```

Предложенный вариант позволит сохранить место.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, не очень, потому что

* Рано или поздно в настройке окажется символ '`;`'
* Есть функции serialize/unserialize, результат съест больше места, но все равно свой велосипед писать не стоит
* Каждый раз, когда значение надо обновить, надо беспокоиться о сохранении всего массива. И представьте эффективность, если по какой-то причине происходит каскадное обновление настроек (на самом деле на мелком проекте наплевать, но мы же пытаемся делать все чисто, так?)

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть пятый вариант: evercookie.
Если не хочется занимать место на сервере - хороший вариант. Но информацию из всех этих хранилищ тоже можно вынести, проверял уже.